# Are there other words in Spanish that can't be written? (like sal-le)

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, palabras-raras, terminología

Recently, I learned that there is at least one Spanish word that can be pronounced but not written.

It is the imperative form of 'salirle'. It is pronounced as 'sal-le' and the written form should be 'salle'. But according to pronunciation rules, that word must be pronounced as 'sá-lle'. So the word can't be written at all ([more details here](http://www.unaracnidounacamiseta.com/2011/02/10/la-palabra-que-no-se-puede-escribir/)).

Are there other words in Spanish that can't be written? Has this phenomena a name?

Comment: Very interesting. Although if the Spanish-speaking world stopped with this *tú* business and started using *vos*, this case wouldn't be a problem at all :)

Comment: You say this can't be written following normal rules, so what does one write when using this word? Surely there is written text somewhere where this word has appeared? Do people just write 'sal-le' like you have in your question?

Comment: Can anyone give an example of a sentence in which _sal-le_ would actually come up? I can't think of one. And I feel like, since there are Academies, if it were a usable word they would have figured out how to write it already.

Comment: Actually I think that's incorrect because de verb is not "salirle" but "salir" and the imperative form is "sal". It's true that you can 't use de imperative with the reflexive third person form, but as Garrigus Carraig I can't think any situation with the need form this imperative with this refleive could come up.

Comment: Two examples: "salirle al paso" or "salirle caro" in their imperative forms ("sal-le al paso", "sal-le caro"). The imperative form is not very usual, but certainly not extremely rare. Please note that the explanation about sal-le in the external link is an actual response from RAE.

Comment: I'm pasting a comment on the same article you linked:  “Salir al encuentro DE alguien” no puede ser reemplazada por “Sal-le al encuentro”, pues “de alguien” no es objeto y por lo tanto no puede sustituirse por el pronombre “le”. Sería “Sal a su encuentro”. Para que existiese “Sal-le al encuentro” la frase debería ser “Sal al encuentro a María”, y dicha frase no es correcta."

Comment: Catalan / valenciano has a way of distinguishing between *ll* and a double-*l*, and the standard Spanish keyboard layout allows typing *sal·le* with shift-3. Whether that would be understood outside north-eastern Spain, I'm not sure.

Comment: The corresponding verb forms of *resalir* and *sobresalir* cannot be written either, since these verbs are conjugated exactly like *salir*. This is too evident, so I just thought I'd make a comment rather than write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La clase zoológica de los mamíferos se divide en varias familias, que en lenguaje corriente se designan con palabras esdrújulas. Por ejemplo los bóvidos, cánidos, cérvidos, félidos y camélidos.

Los cerdos y jabalíes se agrupan en la familia de los **suidos**.

Esta palabra, en concordancia con el resto de las familias, se pronuncia como si tuviera tres sílabas y el acento se marca en la **u**. El problema es que por norma de la RAE la combinación de dos vocales cerradas siempre es diptongo.

Traspasar la pronunciación de la palabra a su ortografía es imposible, porque **súidos** con tilde es ilegal. No queda otra que escribirla sin tilde, de modo que quien la lea por primera vez va a pensar que se pronuncia como **ruidos**.

Comment: No habría, como lo veo, nada ilegal con súido porque sin la tilde, la i quedaría como la vocal nuclear. El hablante tendría que saber que hay hiato, que solo no se marcar siempre en castellano. Aislar y enviar parecen tener dos sílabas, pero tienen tres para muchos hablantes. Si *envio* existiera, habría dos formas posibles de pronunciarlo /'en.bi.o/, /'en.bjo/ igual que hay dos formas para enviar: /en.bi'ar/, /en'bjar/. Hay que saber si hace hiato o no.

Comment: Pero en _aislar, enviar y "envio"_ el acento va lejos del par de vocales. En cambio en _suido_ la vocal tónica de la palabra es la que no se puede marcar. Del mismo modo si existiera la palabra _rúido_ no se podría escribir.

Comment: Ruido tiene dos posibilidades de lectura: /ru'i.do/ y /'rwi.do/. Rúido, en cambio, ofrecería /'ruj.do/ y /'ru.i.do/. Pero no sería mala idea consultar con la RAE para aclararlo, pero creo que súido sería la forma preferida

Comment: Bueno, me equivoco. Prefieren sin tilde, aunque el diccionario nota que por etimología su naturaleza trisilábica

Comment: “Porque **súidos** con tilde es ilegal” — ¿Por qué ilegal? ¿Qué tiene de ilegal? ¿⟨úi⟩ no es legal según la RAE? En cualquier caso, diría que traspasar la pronunciación /ˈsu.i.do/ a una ortografía inequívoca sería bastante fácil. Mismo si aceptamos que _súido_ representa únicamente /ˈsuj.do/ disilábico, _súïdo_ (y tal vez _súhido_ también) representaría /ˈsu.i.do/. La RAE dice que este uso del diéresis es ‘poético’, pero no veo por qué no se debería usar en lugares como éste, donde hay una verdadera ambigüedad a resolver.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _Suido_ es esdrújula y no hay cómo saberlo. Efectivamente en el diccionario de la RAE aparece sin tilde, porque no puedes ponérsela. Es, por decir, una esdrújula a la que se le ha quitado el derecho de llevar tilde y está condenada a no ser pronunciada como tal.

Comment: @Rodrigo Puede ser que soy yo el que he mal entendido la pregunta, pero según yo está preguntando si hay palabras españolas cuya pronunciación no se puede representar siguiendo los principios de la ortografía española. Esta es otra pregunta que si hay palabras cuya ortografía oficial no corresponde a su pronunciación. _Suido_ es ejemplo de lo posterior, pero no del anterior: es _posible_ representar su pronunciación siguiendo la ortografía española; sólo es que la forma oficial no lo hace.

Comment: Por qué no súhido? La h muda es una forma de romper diptongos que se usa, por ejemplo, en palabras de origen árabe. @guifa

Comment: @Rafael "__3.__ La *h* intercalada no influye en absoluto en la consideración como diptongo o como hiato de una secuencia vocálica. Así, hay grupos de vocales con *h* intermedia que forman diptongo: *ahijado, ahumar, prohibir,* y otros que forman hiato: *ahínco, turbohélice, prohíbe*." http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=GoV5Y32DaD60gSzhl5

Comment: @ukemi, wow, gracias, no tenía idea. Otra cosa en que no hablo como la RAE. Para mi es natural separar a.hi.ja.do, a.hu.mar y pro.hi.bir. Reconozco que otros acentos las juntan, pero me suena ajeno y creí que era parte de la variabilidad del castellano...

Comment: @Rafael la ASALE habla allí de la ortografía y no de la pronunciación en sí. A propósitos de la escritura, la *h* no vale nada para calcular la necesidad o no de un tilde.  Habrá los que dirán «pero no necesito un tilde en *buho* porque la *h* divide las vocales» pero lo que la ASALE quiere decir es que debemos tratar la palabra como si fuera *buo*, tildándola si es necesario (lo es, así, *búho*).  También dicen «cada secuencia vocálica será considerada siempre un hiato o siempre un diptongo al colocar las tildes, **con independencia de su pronunciación real** dentro de la palabra».

Answer (score 17):

Si tu coche tiene una baca (esa estructura metálica en forma de parrilla que puedes colocar sobre el techo de un automóvil, para llevar encima equipajes) mal atornillada, encima de la baca llevas una vaca (cosa difícil, pero lingüísticamente posible), y en una curva pierdes ambas, imagino que puedes decir (oralmente) "salieron despedidas las [b/v]acas" (los sonidos [b] y [v] son idénticos en castellano), pero no puedes escribirlo.

Comment: Very creative indeed.

Comment: This phenomenon is common in English-language humor, where.  I imagine the same is true of many languages, including Spanish. And IMHO, it's a different phenomenon than the one the question is asking about.

Comment: Excelente respuesta.

Comment: Siguiendo el ejemplo de Teleclavo , se pueden formar frases similares (que se pueden decir pero no escribir) con otras parejas de palabras homófonas con _"b"_ y _"v"_, como "voto" y "boto", "vate" y "bate", "vaqueta" y "baqueta" o "barón" y "varón", "savia" y "sabia"

Answer (score 10):

This orthographic issue also occurs in the names of certain chemicals:

| English | Spanish |
| --- | --- |
| *N*-methyl leucine | [*N*-metilleucina](https://mgclaros.blogspot.com.es/2017/11/metil-leucina-o-metilleucina.html) |
| methyllysine | [metillisina](http://diccionario-internacional.com/definitions/?spanish_word=methyllysine) |

Hyphens are technically disallowed from resolving the ambiguous pronunciation, since this character is [reserved](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_spanish/chemistry%3B_chem_sci_eng/4761128-%CE%B5_n_alkyl_lysine.html) (in chemical names) for numerical prefixes etc.

Note however that in real world use the word is written in a number of ways, both with the *ll*:

> [***N<sup>6</sup>*-metillisina**)](http://www.latamjpharm.org/resumenes/34/8/LAJOP_34_8_1_4.pdf)

> [... residuo **N-metillisina**](https://books.google.es/books?id=A4FlhoNWTn8C&pg=PA586&lpg=PA586&dq=metillisina)

and without:

> [**n-metil-lisina**...](http://milksci.unizar.es/bioquimica/temas/aminoacids/aminoacidos.html)

> [..., - leucina, **-(N-metil)leucina**](https://patentados.com/2007/analogos-de-tamadarina-y-didemnina)

> [**Metil-lisina**... **Metil lisina**](https://books.google.es/books?id=z6iMx642m_wC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=metillisina)

---

**Note:** This phenomenon (with *salirle*) has been discussed a few times previously on the internet:

- http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/salle

https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-palabra-que-no-se-puede-escribir-6407/

[https://unaracnidounacamiseta.com/2011/02/10/la-palabra-que-no-se-puede-escribir/](https://web.archive.org/web/20110212031410/https://unaracnidounacamiseta.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/la-palabra-que-no-se-puede-escribir/)
 - https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=39858
 - http://barrapunto.com/article.pl?sid=11/02/10/2335255  
 - https://www.taringa.net/posts/ciencia-educacion/9168761/Insolito-bug-en-el-idioma-espanol-no-permite-escribir-un.html  
 - http://losfilologossomosnecesarios.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/no-todo-se-puede-escribir-en-espanol.html  
 - https://www.meneame.net/story/palabra-que-no-puede-escribir

Answer (score 5):

A la vista del [reciente descubrimiento](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25636/12637) de que una forma antigua del imperativo del verbo *valer* es *val*, nada impedía que se formara el imperativo *val·le*. Según el ejemplo [que propuso @guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25636/imperative-form-of-valer/25641?noredirect=1#comment41792_25641):

> Válgale Dios, válgale el Diablo, válgale quién pueda, a mí no me importa, joder, *val·le* tú.

Lo malo es que hoy día sí que hay algo lo impide: que *val* ya no es un imperativo válido, dado que la forma actual es *vale*.

Comment: Noto que prefieres la ortografía catalana (con punto volado) y no la asturiana (con guion)....ya veo lo catalanista que eres ;-)   (dígolo pura y sinceramente de broma, aquí no pretendo entrar en política)

Comment: @guifa fíjate que a día de hoy desconocía ese uso del guion en el asturianu. Lo tendré en cuenta en el futuro. :-D

Comment: Lo pones entre verbo y pronombre cuando el verbo termina en *s* y el pronombre empieza con *s* (por ejemplo, *cues-se* [se cuese]) o lo mismo pero con L: val-lo.  Como hay una regla por la que los verbos *-er* cuya raíz termina en L o S (o Z R N, pero en estos casos no es posible el guion) pierden la vocal, suele ocurrir mucho ya que todo verbo se puede poner en forma impersonal, y la mayoría de los verbos tienen usos transitivos (intransitivo no *val*, porque los pronombres indirectos son *-y* y -*yos*—siempre con guion por no sé qué razón) y que la enclisis es el posicionamiento por omisión

Comment: @walen: ¿no daría lugar a confusión con el imperativo de *salar*: (usted) sale?

Comment: @walen no con "fue" pero si con "su"