# Segunda persona de singular de imperativo de 'salir', en forma pronominal

Tags: ortografía, conjugación

Por un lado, el imperativo de `salir` en segunda persona de singular (sin forma pronominal) es `sal`.

Por otro lado, a los verbos pueden añadir el sufijo `-le` que funciona como pronombre personal (significando `a él`, `a ella` o `a ello`), por ejemplo, `cómprale`, `escríbele`, `regálale`.

Cuando queremos usar la tercera persona de singular de imperativo de salir, con pronombre, sería `sálgale`, *¿pero qué pasaría con la segunda persona del singular?*

En lenguaje hablado sería algo así como `sal·le`, haciendo una pausa entre las dos `l`, pero no se puede escribir en español, ya que al haber dos `l` se pronunciaría con otro sonido (`ll`).

Comment: Relacionado: [Are there other words in Spanish that can't be written? (like sal-le)](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1950/1674)

Comment: La forma pronominal de salir como mandato es *salte (tú)* (cf. *sálga(n)se Vd(s).*, *salíos vosotros*, *salite vos*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La pregunta [Are there other words in Spanish that can't be written? (like sal-le)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1950/1674) contiene a su vez [un enlace](http://unaracnidounacamiseta.com/2011/02/10/la-palabra-que-no-se-puede-escribir/) en el que comentan que la RAE ya reconoció que *sal·le* es una palabra del español que se puede pronunciar (haciendo una pausa entre las dos *l*) pero que no se puede escribir, porque al escribirla cambia su pronunciación. Y el español no tiene en su ortografía contemplado el signo · como sí lo tiene el catalán, por ejemplo.

El artículo finaliza diciendo que posiblemente este sea el único *bug* conocido del idioma español. Dado que suele ser una pregunta recurrente, la propia RAE [ha explicado](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/739770002929266688) que

> Son incorrectas *«salle» y *«sal.le» para escribir el imperativo «sal» + clítico «le».

y ha liberado [un documento](http://static.ow.ly/docs/imperativo%20de%20salir%20con%20cl%C3%ADtico_4REK.pdf) (PDF) que dice:

> [...] este sería el único caso en el que aparecerían dentro de una palabra española dos eles contiguas, cada una de ellas perteneciente a una sílaba diferente, secuencia fónica cuya representación se halla bloqueada en nuestro sistema gráfico, puesto que concurriría con el dígrafo *ll* [...].

Y concluye:

> [...] lo natural es que, en su lugar, se generen expresiones en las que el pronombre de dativo se sustituye por el sintagma correspondiente (o, incluso, por un posesivo: *sal a su encuentro*) o en las que el verbo *salir* aparece en infinitivo como núcleo de una perífrasis modal de obligación (*tener que* + infinitivo; *deber* + infinitivo; *haber de* + infinitivo; la impersonal *haber que* + infinitivo) [...]

Y cita:

> *«Mas tú, guardando el sin igual decoro que guardas en empresas exquisitas, **sal al encuentro** luego **a esta canalla**, puesto que perderás en la batalla»* (Cervantes *Comedia famosa de la casa de los celos y selvas de Ardenia* [España 1615]);
>
> *«Mira, aquella es la Sunamitis. **Sal a su encuentro**, y dile: ¿Te va bien a ti y a tu marido y a tu hijo?»* (Molina *Misal completo* [España 1943]);
>
> *«**Hay que salir al encuentro** de los chismes, dijo la maestra»* (Allende *Eva Luna* [Chile 1987]).

Curiosamente, este *bug* no se da en los países con voseo, en los que el imperativo de segunda persona de singular de *[salir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X42OtRP)* es *salí (vos)*, por lo que en dichos países el imperativo más el clítico sería *salile*, perfectamente válido.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, me ha gustado especialmente lo de _posiblemente este sea el único bug conocido del idioma español_ :)

Comment: No es un *bug* del idioma, sino del sistema ortográfico.  Se puede cambiar la forma de escribir fácilmente sin incurrir cambio alguno en la forma hablada.  El problema, imagino, es que siendo el único ejemplo, parece ridículo hace una regla general solo por aquella palabra, aunque podría decir que es *salle* y que tiene una pronunciación irregular.  En catalán tienen *l·l*, y en asturiano se usa *l-l* (y *s-s* cuando surge), pero son cosas que ocurren con mucha más frecuencia.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Excelente respuesta, Carlos. Aquí, en Argentina, no tenemos el problema, como te imaginarás, por el uso del voseo. Normalmente diríamos: "Salile al encuentro" - "Salile al paso"