# Imperative form of "valer"

Tags: etimología, verbos, historia, arcaísmos

I recently came across a book listing the imperative tú form of the verb *valer* as ***val***. I also came across a website that agreed; however, when I checked on RAE.es, Wordreference.com, and Spanishdict.com, the conjugation was listed as ***vale***. Is ***val*** a mistake or is it an archaic conjugation.

Comment: For DRAE ["val" is a shortening of "valle"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bHN9HUG). Could you link to the website were you saw "val" as imperative of "valer". If possible cite the book as well. That could help to validate those sources.

Comment: Interesting. *Val* is the Asturian form although it's possible that in the past it was also shortened in Castilian, I know I've seen other -er verbs that were (even in the indicative) but I can't recall if *valer* was one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the *[Nueva Gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KMpWrWDBbICqgLP,)* describes it:

> El verbo *valer* poseía un imperativo monosilábico (*val*), usado generalmente en su variante pronominal.  La forma antigua *valte* equivalía, pues, a la actual *válete*: *Aprieta pues bien con ambos braços tu dicha; que es ella revaladiza como culebre: valte del polvo de tu ser para tenerla asida* (Garau, *Sabio*)

So in effect, yes, the form *val* existed in the past, but it is no longer used.  The RAE's conjugation engine sometimes doesn't include irregular forms even when they're correct (*plugo* shows up for *placer*, but not *plegue*), but they don't ever show archaic verb forms that are no longer considered standard.

I would not use it today.  The only people who speak Spanish today that would ever say *val* are bilingual speakers who also speak Asturian or Catalonian because the verb in the indicative/imperative has that form (and really only when speaking those languages).

Comment: So, the old imperative _val_ could also create [a word like "sal·le"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1950/12637)? Would "val·le" have any sense?

Comment: @Charlie  Sure.  Consider the common expression and its millions of variations *válgame Dios* or *válganme las orejas* or similar.  There's nothing to prevent you (person being commanded) from being the one that does the valiendo, and of course you can use *le* instead of *me*, hence: *válgale Dios, válgale el Diablo, válgale quién pueda, a mí no me importa, joder, val-le tú*

Comment: @Charlie Note: in Guifa's example, in written Catalan this orthographic ambiguity is avoided as post-enclitic pronouns are hyphenated when following a consonant e.g. *val-li, val-lo, val-la, val-los, val-les* etc