# ¿Cómo se llaman las palabras que tienen un significado diferente al poner el acento en una sílaba diferente?

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, fonología

Veamos el caso de `/jubilo/`, donde tenemos:

- [***jú***bilo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MZHoJe3)
- *ju**bi**lo* (de [jubilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MZ4npwR%7CMZ6ZvZa%7CMZBwxfV))
- *jubi**ló*** (id)

Y lo mismo con ánimo / animo / animó y muchas otras, como [recoge un twit](https://twitter.com/JRhodesPianist/status/996671102075187200).

En él se habla de estas palabras como ***tritónicas***, que es un concepto que el DLE no recoge pero que es fácilmente deducible y creable a partir del hecho que son tres posibles fonologías ([*tónico*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a0xKFMI): *2. adj. Fonética. Que tiene acento prosódico*).

Sin embargo, imaginemos que una palabra de este tipo tiene cuatro sílabas. ¿Las hay? ¿Habría algún término para designarla?

Comment: _Pacífico_ tiene cuatro sílabas pero no cuatro acentos.

Comment: @Rodrigo en este caso, ¿sería tritónica? Tiene tres posibles significados según dónde se ponga el acento, pero el 4.º (en _pa_) no coincide con ninguna palabra conocida. No sé cómo está _legislado_ todo esto.

Comment: Lo veo complicado, las palabras sobresdrújulas no son muy comunes y casi siempre son verbos con sufijos pronominales o adverbios acabados en *-mente* y no creo que palabras así  puedan ser "cuatritónicas".

Comment: no creo que tengan nombre, 
mientras que los homonimos y homofonos dependen de su escritura y sonido, las palabras de las que tu hablas carecen de esto: tienen escritura diferente, suenan diferente y tienen significado diferente.  

creo que como tales no podria considerarse una relacion entre ellas

Comment: interesante, las palabras las hay, ditonicsa, tritonicas y tetratonicas, podriamso decir que en general son palabras "multitonicas"?

Comment: Estas palabras muestran claramente el porque es tan importante la tilde en el español.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todavía no hay ningún termino 'oficial' para estes grupos de palabras.

Sin embargo, hay varios sitios del web que describan estas palabras también como *tritónicas*:

> PALABRAS TRITÓNICAS
>
> Hay palabras que tienen los mismos sonidos y que se escriben con las mismas letras que otras, pero la situación de su sílaba tónica varía y con ella también cambia el significado. Se llaman tritónicas aquellas palabras que pueden tener la sílaba tónica en tres (tri-) posiciones diferentes.
>
> - [http://guindo.pntic.mec.es/~mortiz2/fpacent_palab_tritónicas.htm](http://guindo.pntic.mec.es/~mortiz2/fpacent_palab_trit%C3%B3nicas.htm)

En [*La acentuación española: nuevo manual de las normas acentuales*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HCF0qCCw3GMC&pg=PA102&dq=ej%C3%A9rcito+ejercito+ejercit%C3%B3) por Roberto Veciana, él las llama ***"voces homónimas acentuales (trítonas)"***.

En [*Gramática de la lengua castellana, métrica y filosofía del lenguaje*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5RITAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA137&dq=ej%C3%A9rcito+ejercito+ejercit%C3%B3) se llaman ***"voces homófonas de significación varia"*** (pero también se incluye parejas como *botar, votar* etc).

En inglés hay un termino ***heteronym*** para palabras homógrafas que no son sinónimas ni homófonas (pero en castellano, el cognado *heterónimo* significa [algo distinto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26243/18348)), e.g.:

- *subject* `/ˈsʌb.dʒɛkt/` (sustantivo)
  *subject* `/sʌbˈdʒɛkt/` (verbo)

Si no cuentas<sup>1</sup> palabras con/sin acentos como distintos 'grafas', puedes describirlos como:

1. "homógrafas no homófonas"
2. "heterónimos" (expandiendo la definición para incluir la significación lingüística inglesa / usarlo como un calco)

[image]

---

**Notas:**

1. <sup>Usar esta definición haría que *periodo/período* etc se incluyeran en la sección verde.</sup>

- <sup>Explicación de [*salle / sal-le / sal·le*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1950/18348).</sup>