# ¿Cómo se deletrean las "palabras" con varias letras iguales seguidas?

Tags: pronunciación, letras, deletreo

Por ejemplo, para deletrear el comienzo de una dirección web, como `www.algo.com`, he oído todas estas fórmulas:

- *uve doble, uve doble, uve doble*
- *tres uve(s) dobles* (lo he oído con S y sin S)
- *triple uve doble*

Ídem para palabras con LL o con RR, por ejemplo `arrullo`: ¿se dice "*a, erre, erre, u, ele, ele, o*", o "*a, erre doble, u, ele doble, o*", o una combinación de ambas? ¿O es válido seguir diciendo "*elle*" cuando encontramos el dígrafo LL, aunque ya no sea una letra?

¿Cuál es la fórmula adecuada?
¿Hay alguna diferencia entre las que se identifican con un único sonido (LL, RR), las que son más bien dos sonidos separados (CC, NN) y las que no son ningún sonido en particular (WWW)?

Comment: Mi opinión es no hay realmente una opción correcta (o una o varias incorrectas). En un concurso de deletreo, puede haber normas preestablecidas (que serán más o menos arbitrarias). La RAE no tiene ningún tipo de normativa o recomendación acerca del deletreo (que yo sepa). Las tres opciones que propones en el fondo transmiten el mismo tipo de información. Dada la definición del DRAE: [deletrear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C6bvTMf) si incluimos el decir las sílabas vas a tener un problema con esos "www". O puedes querer enfatizar lo de "Decir **separadamente**" de la definición y favorecer una opción

Comment: _triple uve doble_ seems really confusing to me but I think if you expect non-native speakers like me to understand either of the other two would work better.

Comment: _Triple uve doble_... ¿sextuple uve?

Comment: ¡Interesante pregunta!  ¿Podrías aclarar la situación en que esta duda surge?  Estoy imaginando: estoy tratando de explicar a mi suegra cómo hacer cierta cosa en la computadora, y no estoy con ella en su casa, sino que le estoy dando las instrucciones por teléfono.  Quiero darle una dirección (url), por ejemplo, "Doña Mari, ve por favor a esta dirección: escribe tres veces la letra A, y luego viene 'punto com'."  ¿Eso es, más o menos lo que estás preguntando?

Comment: ¡Gracias por aclarar! Pues no sé si esto sería adecuado para una respuesta, pero lo que se me ocurre decir si imagino esa situación, es "Escribe tres veces la letra A, y luego escribe etc."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo no he encontrado ninguna recomendación o norma de la RAE sobre deletreo. De acuerdo a la definición del diccionario, [deletrear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C6bvTMf) es

> 1. intr. Decir separadamente las letras de cada sílaba, las sílabas de cada palabra y luego la palabra entera
> 2. tr. Decir el nombre de cada una de las letras que constituyen una palabra.

En este artículo ["Breves de la Actualidad Lingüística"](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/breves-de-la-actualidad-linguistica-6376/), Fundéu interpreta como **esencial** ese "Decir separadamente":

> Deletrear, según el DRAE, es **pronunciar aislada y separadamente las letras de una palabra**

Por lo que deberíamos usar la primera opción que propones ("*uve doble, uve doble, uve doble*") para algo como "www". Es interesante que Fundéu propone (respecto al deletreo de "chanchullo", que usan como ejemplo para expplicar cómo ha cambiado el deletreo de esa palabra de «**che** – a – ene – **che** – u – **elle** – o» a «**ce – hache** – a – ene – **ce – hache** – u – **ele – ele** – o») que

> [...] otra posibilidad mucho mejor sería conservar el deletreo anterior, y cambiar la definición de la palabra deletreo o inventar una nueva que la sustituya, pues ya no se trataría de pronunciar las letras sino las letras o dígrafos de las palabras.

Por lo que entiendo que Fundéu interpreta que decir "*tres uve(s) dobles*" y "*triple uve doble*", no es realmente una forma de deletreo, si no otra cosa, pues, aunque "www" no sea un dígrafos o una palabra en sí, si no decimos las letras una a una y por separado no estamos deletreando.

Dado que "www" encima no es una palabra, no habría razón para intentar "pronunciar un trígrafo" o similar.

El ejemplo de ese artículo usa `chanchullo` que tiene dos eles seguidas, y entiendo que haremos lo mismo con palabras con dos erres (como `arroyo`) y que podemos extrapolar a "www".

Aparte, la segunda acepción de la definición, "Decir el nombre de cada una de las letras que constituyen una palabra" nos lleva a *interpretar* que deletrear es decir "ele - ele", y no "dos eles", pues no decimos el nombre particular de cada letra, si no la *cantidad* de las mismas (dentro del orden en el que aparecen).

Comment: En Colombia a singo "w" le decimos "doble u" y no ha calado llamarla "uve doble",  tanto así que existe una cadena radial denominada "La doble U"

Comment: @walen yo interpreto que preguntan "cómo se dice/pronuncia" y no "cómo se deletrea", y eso responde la RAE (transmitir la información de lo que está escrito no es necesariamente deletrear). Tú sabes decir "llama" cuando ves escrita la palabra, pero deletreas como "ele - ele - a ...". Con "www" la cosa se complica porque no es pronunciable, a diferencia de otras nomenclaturas. Si en vez de "www"  la url usase otro host (digamos WAN) la pregunta de "cómo lo decimos" ciertamente no tendría sentido. Es como "cómo de dice ["salle"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1950/5481) y cómo se deletrea?"